# SQL Server: How to customize one column in Order By clause out of many other columns in order by

Tags: t-sql

I have store procedure which return data fine and it was developed by some one else who now not in touch.

Output now looks like
[image]

Here i am attaching a part of the query which return data.

```
SET @sql = '      
Select XX.*,'''' scale,Isnull(AllowComma,''FALSE'') AllowComma,Isnull(AllowedDecimalPlace,''0'') AllowedDecimalPlace,      
 Isnull(AllowPercentageSign,''FALSE'') AllowPercentageSign,Isnull(CurrencySign,'''') CurrencySign,Isnull(BM_Denominator,'''') BM_Denominator      
From       
(      
---- Broker Detail      
Select AA.Section,AA.LineItem,Csm.DisplayInCSM ,AA.BrokerCode Broker,AA.BrokerName,'''' BM_Element,'''' BM_Code,AA.Ord,AA.[Revise Date],AA.LineItemId,      
Csm.ID,[FontName],[FontStyle],[FontSize],[UnderLine],[BGColor],[FGColor],[Indent],[Box],[HeadingSubHeading],      
'+@PeriodCols+','+@PeriodColsComment +',LineItem_Comment,BrokerName_Comment,Date_Comment      
From tblCSM_ModelDetails Csm LEFT OUTER JOIN  (      
Select b.*,L.ID LineItemId         
From #TmpAll_Broker_LI b      
INNER JOIN TblLineItemTemplate L ON TickerID='''+@TickerID+''' AND b.LineItem= L.LineItem      
 ) AA ON Csm.LineItemId=AA.LineItemId      
WHERE Csm.CSM_ID='+TRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(10),@CSM_Id))+' AND Csm.BMID=0 AND Type !=''SHEET''      
UNION       
----- Consensus      
Select Section, b.LineItem,DisplayInCSM, '''' Broker,'''' BrokerName,'''' BM_Element,'''' BM_Code, Ord,'''' [Revise Date],L.ID LineItemID,      
Csm.ID,[FontName],[FontStyle],[FontSize],[UnderLine],[BGColor],[FGColor],[Indent],[Box],[HeadingSubHeading],      
'+@PeriodCols+','+@PeriodColsComment +',LineItem_Comment,BrokerName_Comment,Date_Comment      
From #TmpZacksCons b      
INNER JOIN TblLineItemTemplate L ON TickerID='''+@TickerID+''' AND b.LineItem= L.LineItem      
INNER JOIN tblCSM_ModelDetails Csm ON Csm.LineItemID=L.ID      
WHERE Csm.CSM_ID='+TRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(10),@CSM_Id))+' AND Csm.BMID=0      
---- Blue Metrics      
 UNION      
Select Section, b.LineItem,DisplayInCSM,'''' Broker,'''' BrokerName,BM_Element,Code BM_Code, Ord,'''' [Revise Date],L.ID LineItemID,      
Csm.ID,[FontName],[FontStyle],[FontSize],[UnderLine],[BGColor],[FGColor],[Indent],[Box],[HeadingSubHeading],      
'+@PeriodCols+','+@PeriodColsComment +',LineItem_Comment,BrokerName_Comment,Date_Comment      
From #TmpBM b      
INNER JOIN TblLineItemTemplate L ON TickerID='''+@TickerID+''' AND b.LineItem= L.LineItem      
INNER JOIN tblCSM_ModelDetails Csm ON Csm.BMID=b.code AND Csm.LineItemID=L.ID      
WHERE Csm.CSM_ID='+TRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(10),@CSM_Id))+'      
AND Ord IS NOT NULL      
) XX       
Left Outer Join tblLiConfig ZZ      
On XX.Section=ZZ.Section And XX.LineItem=ZZ.LI And ZZ.Ticker='''+@Ticker+'''      
Order by ID,Ord,BM_Code,LineItem,BrokerName'
```

**Now broker Name is not coming as alphabetical order and it is the issue.**

see this line at the bottom `Order by ID,Ord,BM_Code,LineItem,BrokerName`

When i try to change this order by like `Order by ID,Ord,BM_Code,LineItem,BrokerName IN (SELECT BrokerName FROM #Brokers ORDER BY BrokerName ASC)'`  then getting error like **clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.**

**in my order by there are many columns and data is getting order by that way but i need to show broker name in alphabetical order but i am not being able. so please some one guide me how can i customize this sql.**

Here i have not attached my full store procedure code because it is very large. looking for suggestion & help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short version**

The `ORDER BY` is doing what is expected - ordering first by ID, then Ord, then BM_Code, then LineItem, then BrokerName.

Within ID 76187, the next field to order by is `Ord` - which it sorts from 30911, to 31097.

If it previously ordered by BrokerName, it was only by chance - or that Ord was ordered the same way as BrokerName.

My initial suggestion is to re-order your sort e.g., `ORDER BY ID, BM_Code, LineItem, BrokerName, Ord`

**Longer explanation of issue**

In SQL, underlying data is treated as a set and ordering doesn't matter.

For example, if you have a variable @x and you were testing `IF @x IN (1,2,3,4,5)` will produce the same result as `IF @x in (5,4,3,2,1)`.

In your example, you're putting an ORDER BY into the sub-query you're checking with the IN e.g., `ORDER BY ... BrokerName IN (SELECT BrokerName FROM #Brokers ORDER BY BrokerName ASC)`. The order of that sub-query isn't allowed, and wouldn't do anything anyway.

The *only* sort that matters (other than for a few things like TOP) is the final sort - when displaying the data.

That being said, even if you removed the ORDER BY in the sub-query, it wouldn't help you with your issue

- The SQL is not likely to work anyway - ORDER BY needs a value - you may have needed to make it `CASE WHEN BrokerName IN (...) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`
- Which also won't help, as the issue is that `Ord` is sorted before `BrokerName` anyway.

**UPDATE following comment**

Fundamentally, the statement that provides the actual report is

```
SET @sql = '      
Select XX.*,'''' scale,Isnull(AllowComma,''FALSE'') AllowComma,Isnull(AllowedDecimalPlace,''0'') AllowedDecimalPlace,      
     Isnull(AllowPercentageSign,''FALSE'') AllowPercentageSign,Isnull(CurrencySign,'''') CurrencySign,Isnull(BM_Denominator,'''') BM_Denominator      
From (<a whole lot of calculations/cpode>) XX       
    Left Outer Join tblLiConfig ZZ
        On XX.Section=ZZ.Section And XX.LineItem=ZZ.LI And ZZ.Ticker='''+@Ticker+'''      
Order by ID,Ord,BM_Code,LineItem,BrokerName'
```

The last line on there provides the ordering of the data coming from this procedure.

To get a different order, you need to change the order of the fields shown - moving BrokerName more towards the start of the list, and Ord towards the end.

e.g.,

```
SET @sql = '      
Select XX.*,'''' scale,Isnull(AllowComma,''FALSE'') AllowComma,Isnull(AllowedDecimalPlace,''0'') AllowedDecimalPlace,      
     Isnull(AllowPercentageSign,''FALSE'') AllowPercentageSign,Isnull(CurrencySign,'''') CurrencySign,Isnull(BM_Denominator,'''') BM_Denominator      
From (<a whole lot of calculations/cpode>) XX       
    Left Outer Join tblLiConfig ZZ
        On XX.Section=ZZ.Section And XX.LineItem=ZZ.LI And ZZ.Ticker='''+@Ticker+'''      
Order by ID,BrokerName,BM_Code,LineItem,Ord'
```

The above probably sorts by BrokerName too early - but it's up to you to determine what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. i will test and let you know. i gave marked it as answer for your effort Sir.

Comment: I hope it makes sense - if you have any questions, please feel free to ask

Comment: columns in my case is dynamic `@PeriodCols`. now how can i mention that in my dynamic sql that column value must not be null. i do not want to print that row if all dynamic columns values are empty or null

Comment: just post another question. please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927241/sql-server-how-to-mention-dynamic-column-value-should-not-be-null

Comment: Sorry this way order does not solve my problem `ORDER BY ID, BM_Code, LineItem, BrokerName, Ord` should i post full store procedure code which is bit big?

Comment: here is the full SP code https://github.com/karlosRivera/SampleRepo/blob/master/Dynamic%20SP.txt  please have a look and tell me how could i fix sort issue on brokername field.

Comment: I've done an update on the answer. It's still the same answer, but I've given more explanation and an example of what the change should be.